# replace all the values of a hash sequentially with respect to an array

Tags: ruby, hash

Suppose I have a hash,

```
hash = { "name" = > nil, "product" => nil , "price" => nil }
```

and an array

```
a = [ "Bob" , "Fryer" , "20$"]
```

I would like the output be hash

```
{ "name" => "Bob" , "product" => "Fryer" , "price" => "20$"}
```

Tried with `zip`, `merge` and `map`, couldn't get the right one

Comment: For future reference, [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We want to know what you tried. "couldn't get the right one" tells us very little that's useful.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Hash[hash.keys.zip(a)]
 => {"name"=>"Bob", "product"=>"Fryer", "price"=>"20$"}
```

Comment: when i print the hash it doesn't return with the new values. how do i get that

Comment: hash = Hash[hash.keys.zip(a)]

Answer (score 0):

You can get `keys` and `zip` it with array:

```
hash.keys.zip(a).to_h
=> {"name"=>"Bob", "product"=>"Fryer", "price"=>"20$"}
```

Comment: when i print the hash it doesn't return with the new values. how do i get that .